# How to find the limits of $y$ in this surface integral?

Tags: vector-analysis, surface-integrals

Integrate $G(x,y,z) = xyz$ over the triangular surface bounded by the point

$(1,0,0), (0,2,0)$  and     $(0,1,1)$

Now I can calculate the equation of plane formed by the three points is  :

$2x +  y + z = 2$ but I am little confused on how should I calculate the limits for $x$ and $y$

Suppose I take the projection in $x-y$ plane then $z = 0$ then I get

$2x + y = 2$  So $x$ varies from  $0$ to $1$ while $y$ varies from $0$ to $2-2x$

However in  my book The limits of $y$ are given from $1-x$ to $2-2x$. I do not understand where this $1-x$ comes from ?

Can anyone please help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the $xy$-plane, $y$ is bounded by the two lines. One of them is $y=2-2x$ and the other is the line passing through (1,0,0) and (0,1,0), which is the $xy$-projection of the side passing through (1,0,0) and (0,1,1).

Thus, the other limit is given by,

$$y = 1-x$$

i.e. the line passing through (1,0,0) and (0,1,0).

Comment: @ Quanto: But why is this information about the second line lost when I put $z=0$ why does it not show the existence of second line ? Can you please explain this ?

Comment: @zeroflank - Note that along the $y$-direction, the boundaries of the triangle surface are two lines, one line through (1,0,0) and (0,2,0), and the other through (1,0,0) and (0,1,1). Normally, you find the $xy$-projection of a line by setting the $z$-component of the two points to zero. So, the projection points of the first line onto the $xy$-plane are themselves, (1,0,0) and (0,2,0) and the projection points of the second line onto the $xy$-plane are (1,0,0) and (0,1,0).

Comment: The first projection line happens to be the intersection between the plane $z=0$ surface equation $2x +  y + z = 2$, which is why you could obtain by letting $z=0$ in the surface equation. But, this is not true for the second projection line.